# What's going on with `props: { name: string; description: string }`?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I came across this snippet of code and was confused by what's going on with `props: { name: string; description: string }`? As a beginner, I understand the ability to send `props` to components.

However, there seems to be a lot more going on here. If this is something to do with dynamic generation, then I would have understood the object being assigned to props via `=` sign. However, what's up with the semi-colon?

```
export default function InfoCard(props: { name: string; description: string }) {
  return (
    <Card>
      <CardContent>
        <Typography>
          // This evaluates props.name so that the value of props.name will show
          {props.name}
        </Typography>
        <Typography>
          // This evaluates props.description so that the value of props.description will show
          {props.description}
        </Typography>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not valid Javascript: the code here is Typescript, a superset of Javascript.

The object after the `:` is a type annotation meaning that props should be an object with a `name` and a `description` property which are both strings.

The equivalent Javascript is the same without the types annotations:

```
export default function InfoCard(props) {
  return (
    <Card>
      <CardContent>
        <Typography>
          // This evaluates props.name so that the value of props.name will show
          {props.name}
        </Typography>
        <Typography>
          // This evaluates props.description so that the value of props.description will show
          {props.description}
        </Typography>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

You can check the emitted code in the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AMwIYFcA29noHYDGMAlhHnAJJ7IQDCqUCAFGFBGAM4BccA3nHlQBbYDw4woxPAHMA3ImAcCksCTJiJU6XAC+ASj4AoOHCjAY6KOSbGTcADz1GAPlt2HThLTIxgeGK7u7vYAKgCekNJQqGAAFmGBQe4A9MlwIbHEHHDAAG6omOiovtms7BwAdIIicBwQcDCxxQ2xwHD5hW0QyHBlnFXCbQDuxJiYtbEQQ25JfH2V1cA6M8HJ4ZHRcQkrdqEREFEx8YmzcKnpmdl5BUUlvWz9SEoqauR1Lc2NbR3oXT3zFSeymIqlI5BGYwmUx27l4AKBLzBy1O9jW+0OWxOu2Snm8-j8ARmqM8iT0skMOiAA)

Comment: Aaah! Okay, so this is typescript... And not valid in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I write :

```
export default function InfoCard({name , description}) {
  return (
    <Card>
      <CardContent>
        <Typography>
          // This evaluates props.name so that the value of props.name will show
          {name}
        </Typography>
        <Typography>
          // This evaluates props.description so that the value of props.description will show
          {description}
        </Typography>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

Comment: Mmmm... Would you mind doing a bit of commentary here, please?

Comment: ```Destructuring Arguments``` are also available here.This means that instead of once receiving the props as a parameter and then accessing the properties, you can write ```{name , description}```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I appreciate it!

Comment: I am also grateful